# Modal not working with owl carousel

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel, materialize

I am trying to use materialize.css modal inside owl-carousel but it's not working.
I can see only lean-overlay but not the content.
Anybody have idea about it?

Comment: Do you have more than one slider item/slide? The slider doesn't work with only one item.

Comment: Slider is working perfectly but modal inside slider is not working

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried placing the code for the Materialize modals **before** your owl-carousel code?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Could only see the dark overlay come up but no modal content. On inspecting the resulting page, I found that my modal code wasn't getting added in the HTML produced by Owl Carousel. Trying the answer by @adriennetacke worked for me.

Don't place your modals between the Owl Carousel code since they'll be discarded in the result HTML produced. Instead, place your modals separate from the Owl Carousel code and they should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use modal button inside owl carousel, and modal other code outside owl carousel. Create a row below and past your other codes then it should work fine.